# I'm having trouble installing Monogame 3.2 in VS community 2013

Tags: templates, monogame

I can't find the Monogame templates in VS 2013. I've already asked this on Monogame forums and didn't get the answer I needed.
Discussion of problem at
http://community.monogame.net/t/monogame-3-2-2-file-location/2032/8

Answer (score 0):

As seen [here](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop/Installers/Windows/MonoGame.nsi#L253) MonoGame installer looks for `\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#` directory in your documents to decide if you have installed VS2013. I had to create `Visual C#` folder manually and reinstall MonoGame to solve this problem.